# How to fill the div height with a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I want the text inside the paragraph with class text to fill the parent div with class wrap height.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
  color: #513b60;
  font-size: 280%;
}

.content {
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <p class='text'>Some Text</p>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='description'>Image Description</div>
    <img src='images/icon.svg' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a problem here. You text class has margins that make out the size off the div. You'll have to remove those margins. Also i think you can only solve this via js/jq or making the div have a fix height

Answer (score 0):

Here we can get the div height and the assign it as the font size of the text class.

It will all depend as what you have in the content elements. Be carefull because if the font gets to height and the text splits in two lines. It will make your div double its height

```js
$('.text').css('font-size',($('.wrap').height()))
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

.text {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;

  margin-right:5%;
  float: left;
  color: #513b60;
  
}

.content {
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
  <p class='text'>Some Text</p>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='description'>Image Description</div>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/50x50' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

Comment: Upvote for the trick. Also I think, you also need to set line-height of font as the height of "wrap" div, for more accuracy.